# Jquery autocomplete suggestion is not showing under textbox and showing at the bottom of the page in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have a textbox in ASP.Net MVC application at top of my Home page.

```
    @Html.TextBox("place", Model.place,Model.place, new {id="place", @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "Search by Location" })
```

I am using Jquery to get suggestions:

```
     $(document).ready(function () {
    $("#place").autocomplete({
        source: function (request, response) {
            $.ajax({
                url: "/Search/AutoCompleteSearch",
                type: "POST",
                dataType: "json",
                data: { term: request.term },
                success: function (data) {
                    response($.map(data, function (item) {
                        return { label: item.SearchTerm, value: item.SearchTerm };
                    }))

                }
            })
        },
        messages: {
            noResults: "", results: ""
        }
    });
})
```

In my controller i have written the following code:

```
     public JsonResult AutoCompleteSearch(string term)
    {
        var searchResults = frequentsearchtermService.GetTerms(term);
        return Json(searchResults, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

While executing my application it is showing suggestions, but instead of just below the text box, it shows after the footer of my page.

Comment: Possibly a css issue - have you included the relevant css files? Note: there is no point adding `id = "place"` - the helper already does that. I assume the 3rd parameter in `@HtmlTextBox()` is a typo (it specifies the format string!) and you should be using `@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.place, new {@class = "form-control", @placeholder = "Search by Location" })`

Comment: thanks, I figured it out, referrence was not given for these two files 'jquery-ui.js' and  'jquery-ui.css'

Comment: I assumed you were missing the relevant files. You should add an answer and accept it so this is not left in the unanswered queue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

for proper working of the above code, need to give reference to the following script and css files:

```
<link href="~/Content/css/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="~/Content/js/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="~/Content/js/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```